# eclipse issue after installing STS plugin (4.7.1)

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I'm getting the following error :

```
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.web.WebAppProvider.getImage(WebAppProvider.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.Web25LabelProvider.getImage(Web25LabelProvider.java:47)
```

I've tried removing all eclipse project artifacts, but it didn't help.  Does anyone know a workaround for this issue ?  I'd hate to remove STS.

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you installed STS in your existing Eclipse IDE, try the all-in-one distribution: http://spring.io/tools/sts/all

Comment: if you try the all-in-one distribution, you can still open the same workspace and/or projects.

Comment: I was under the impression that the full STS version had an older version of eclipse.  Doesn't look like that's the case.  If you answer the question I'll give you credit for the answer.  thank you